# how to display and return a list with cmake

Tags: cmake

It's my first time with cmake, and I have two questions about lists:

1) How to display a list ?

2) How to return a list in a function ?

Here is my code:

```
function(GET_ALL_DIRS where SEP)
  message (STATUS "Let's search all directories in ${where}")
  file (GLOB TMP_LIST_DIR ${where}${SEP}*)
  foreach (tmp_elem ${TMP_LIST_DIR})
    if (IS_DIRECTORY ${tmp_elem})
      list (APPEND "${every_class}" ${tmp_elem})
      message ("We add ${tmp_elem}")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  list (LENGTH "${every_class}" nb_elem)
  message ("in the list there is ${nb_elem} elements")
  set(${tst} "${every_class}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

GET_ALL_DIRS (includes ${SEP})
list (LENGTH "${tst}" nb_elem)
message ("after get_all_dirs there is ${nb_elem} elements")
```

In the function I have the correct number of elements but after it I have 0...  Why?

Comment: You can print the list with message("${list}"). And returning is just, return the variable containing the list. What's the actual question?

Comment: Whenever you see *<list>* or *<variable>* in the function's paremeters specification, you should use a **name**, not a value obtained via dereference (`${..}`). Correct: `list(APPEND every_class ${tmp_elem})`, `list(LENGTH every_class nb_elem)`, `set(tst ${every_class} PARENT_SCOPE)`,

Comment: Okay, that's exactly the answer of my question, you rock. Edit: I am not able to set your comment as answer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function's parameter specifications

- *<list>*
- *<variable>*

means that CMake expects a **name**, not a dereference of that name (`${..}`).

Correct:

```
list(APPEND every_class ${tmp_elem})

list(LENGTH every_class nb_elem)

set(tst ${every_class} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

---

In CMake name of variable or list may itself be expressed as a result of deference of another variable. Constructions below are **perfectly valid**:

```
set(my_var_name "a")
set(${my_var_name} "some value") # Assign value to variable 'a'

set(name_suffix "b")
list(APPEND list_${name_suffix} "other value") # Appends to a list 'list_b'.
```

Such "dynamic" names are widely used within functions and macros.

Comment: Thanks. No easy to understand in first time but thanks